# Failure of experiment when using base_dockerfile instead of base_image

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

I am attempting to submit an experiment to the Azure Machine Learning Service using a custom docker image.  Everything works ok when I provide the docker image, but fails if I choose to provide a dockerfile.

The use of a base_dockerfile in the DockerSection object is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.environment.dockersection?view=azure-ml-py) and was added in v1.0.53 of the sdk (as noted [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/machine-learning/service/azure-machine-learning-release-notes.md))

Example code:

```
ds = DockerSection()
ds.enabled = True
ds.base_dockerfile = "FROM ubuntu:latest RUN echo 'Hello world!'"
ds.base_image = None
```

The rest of the code is the same as when running with a predefined image from the registry (e.g. setting base_image in the above code).

Example error from ML service is:

> raise ActivityFailedException(error_details=json.dumps(error,
>   indent=4))
>   azureml.exceptions._azureml_exception.ActivityFailedException:
>   ActivityFailedException:
>           Message: Activity Failed: {
>       "error": {
>           "code": "ServiceError",
>           "message": "InternalServerError",
>           "details": []
>       },
>       "correlation": {
>           "operation": null,
>           "request": "K/C4FSnEz74="
>       },
>       "environment": "southcentralus",
>       "location": "southcentralus",
>       "time": "2019-08-20T16:33:17.130928Z" }
>           InnerException None
>           ErrorResponse {"error": {"message": "Activity Failed:\n{\n    \"error\": {\n        \"code\": \"ServiceError\",\n
>   \"message\": \"InternalServerError\",\n        \"details\": []\n
>   },\n    \"correlation\": {\n        \"operation\": null,\n
>   \"request\": \"K/C4FSnEz74=\"\n  },\n    \"environment\":
>   \"southcentralus\",\n    \"location\": \"southcentralus\",\n
>   \"time\": \"2019-08-20T16:33:17.130928Z\"\n}"}}

I've used an example dockerfile in the code above (taken from the SDK documentation) but get the same error if I use the dockerfile that created the base image that works ok from the registry.

Any ideas - or pointers to samples where this actually works - appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue! This appears to be a bug that our team is investigating.

Comment: Hi Roope - thanks for the update.  Is there a github issue tracking it that I can follow?

Comment: The fix should be rolled out by Aug 30th.